# Eclipse javac and java output

Tags: java, eclipse

Please let me know how to view output of "javac"  with arguments and parameters and "java" with arguments and parameter in Eclipse. I am trying to find whether javac and java runtime parameters are correctly passed in eclipse. I am using neon release.

Comment: As I understand you want to run your code with argument in eclipse. If so you just need go to Run -> Run configuration option

Comment: I am trying aspectj with runtime parameters and it is not working out. So output of javac and java arguments will be useful for me.

Comment: Still not clear @Sujit Pandey. "output of javac and java arguments" what is that?

Comment: When we run run through command line we provide arguments to java like -Dxx etc.. But when I run through eclipse I need to make sure the arguments(configured through runtime) are passed correctly to the compiler java or java. Eclipse doesn't display it while compiling or running.

Comment: If you run it in eclipse then the argument is passed in the Run Configuration or you have configured then you just need to debug to see that value

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use a javac, it runs on a jre and use its own jdt compiler. To see compilation errors, Window -> Show view -> Problems. For running goto, Run -> Run configurations.

Comment: You can always compile & run your code from the command line outside eclipse and see if you get results differ from running in eclipse.